# how to loosen the faucet's tap flange?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, caulking

[image]

I want to renew the caulk, surrounding the flange, the one that is adjacent to the wall. Is there a way to loosen the flange, or it comes along with the taps? I'm not sure how to do it, and I'm afraid to break the things.

**UPDATE**

So I've removed the handle, but then I don't know how to remove the stem. I can actually rotate the flange around, meaning that stem and flange is one "component". Am I supposed to pull out the stem, or rotate? I tried carefully    rotate it clock-unwise, it didn't help, neither did pulling out.

[image]

OK, now I unscrewed the large white nut behind the stem, but the stem still doesn't badge, and it doesn't seem I can unscrew it either :

[image]

Comment: The Moen logo will pop off the front of the knob (you can see where because the plastic for the logo piece yellowed more since installation), under it will be the screw to remove the knob.  Once that’s off post another pic if you can’t tell what is next.

Comment: @Tyson, thanks for comment, I updated my question.

Comment: Unscrew the large white plastic nut right behind the stem.

Comment: @Tyson, thanks for response. I finally got the time to work on it. I updated the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2XvFfEP see the notch? There is likely another across from it.  There might be a tool for it, or you might get lucky with two flat blade screw drivers.  Be careful not to damage threads.

Comment: @Tyson, thanks for being patient with me ;) Is that notch on the pipe coming out of the wall, am I right? And I'm supposed to kind of "squeeze" the pipe to let the flange loose and out?

Comment: No that entire inner piece with the notch will screws out along the threads in the outer portion.  Turn the inner piece to unscrew (a long way) thru those threads.  Don’t bend or squeeze anything.

Answer (score 1):

As Tyson suggested, you should start by removing the screw cover

1. Use a small screw driver to pop off the screw cover (with the Moen
   logo).
2. Next unscrew the reviled screw and attempt to pull off the handle.
3. If the handle doesn't come off, go to the hardware store and
       purchase a "Faucet Handle/Compression Sleeve Puller"

[image]

4. You should now be able to remove your flange

Comment: @virualxtc, thanks for comment, I updated my question. So I guess I'll need this tool.